# openni_camera os x build

Tags: macos-snowleopard, openni-camera, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Finally got openni_camera and all its dependencies built on OSX Snow Leopard.
Unfortunately, the openni_node module when it is started
prints 3 times the following message:

`Warning:recursive print statement has occurred. Throwing out recursive print.`

and then exits

This error is similar to this one:
http://answers.ros.org/question/269/openni_nodelaunch-warning-recursive-print
but i am not sure if its caused by the same reasons
Has anyone got the kinect working on os x 10.6, if so, any advices?

**EDIT:**

Hello again, I have now tried the new stack openni_kinect on osx but still no success although now I think that I am really close... These have been my steps:

1. I have installed the kinect on osx using the avin sensor and these steps: http://c4c.posterous.com/installing-openni-kinect-drivers-and-nite-on, This works like a charm
2. I have followed the instructions to install openni_kinect. Initially it did not compile because it did not find a header file from openi, so I have added the option include_libraries(/usr/include/ni), to my Cmakelists.txt
3. Every thing compiles now smoothly, now I try to run the openni_node, so I run: `rosrun openni_camera openni_node` and I get this:

   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
   what(): unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /Users/alalbiol/Programacion/upvsoft/ros/openni_kinect/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 114 :
   number of streams and devices does not match: 2 devices, 3 depth streams, 2 image streams

So I guess that the camera is detected but still something goes wrong, Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9340/openni_camera-os-x-build/) by [Alberto Albiol](https://answers.ros.org/users/262/alberto-albiol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-08**:
can you reply exactly what commands you are issuing and any errors you get. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0